# I want the text selected when a user navigates to the TextBox

Tags: uwp

In a UWP app (C#) I want to have all text selected when the user clicks on a TextBox (or tabs to it). How can I do that?

Comment: this is straight forward, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use the "GotFocus" event, here's an example:

```
    private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }
```

Add this event to your textbox and this will select all text everytime your textbox is selected.